# Unable to access my desktop computer hard disk

Tags: mount, disk

I was working normally on my desktop computer with Windows 8.1, then my power supply stopped working, the PC shut down and it won't turn on again until I replace the power supply (which I can because it's December 31)

I used my converter to connect my FILES (D:) Hard disk via USB to my Ubuntu laptop (It has nothing to do with windows, windows is in another physical hard disk) and I get this error:

[image]

I've read this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation), but it requires you to start Windows (I can't do it) I need some solution I directly on Linux.

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: you can not restart your computer and access to Windows ?

Comment: If you're talking about my Desktop computer, no, the power supply is not working, so I have the disk where I store my files (not the OS) connected via USB to my laptop, like an external drive.

Comment: The link provides a number of options without having to boot into windows.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I tried them but it doesn't work if I follow those instructions, I'm new to Ubuntu relatively and I haven't made this before. I've tried them but I think I'm doing nothing

Comment: It probably not a hibernation issue since it crashed due to power supply. Sometimes I am unable to mount my windows partitions because windows has them flagged to run a disk check next time Windows boots. I think this is what is happening here. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to get it working still from Ubuntu

Install ntfs-3g with

```
 sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g.
```

Then run the ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition.

For example:

ntfsfix /dev/hda6

Make sure to change /dev/hda6 to whatever it actually is.

Once that finishes, try to mount again.

Comment: IT WORKED IT WORKED LOL I'm so happy you saved me!

Comment: What I needed to know was in the error dialog! :P

Comment: Glad I was able to help... P.S - the info you need is often found in the error log, but I didn't see it at first either